# Java spring - Posting a simple form not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to Java and Spring and I am trying to create a simple POST form. Template looks like this:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/notes}" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="noteId" id="note-id">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="note-title" class="col-form-label">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name= "noteTitle" class="form-control" id="note-title" maxlength="20" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="note-description" class="col-form-label">Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="noteDescription" id="note-description" rows="5" maxlength="1000" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <button id="noteSubmit" type="submit" class="d-none"></button>
</form>
```

And this is the controller for this POST endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/notes")
    public String postNote(@ModelAttribute Note note, Authentication authentication, Model model) throws IOException {
        User user = this.userService.getUser(authentication.getName());
        Integer userid = user.getUserId();
        noteService.createNote(note, userid);
        model.addAttribute("success",true);
        model.addAttribute("message","New note added successfully!");
        return "result";
    }
```

The noteService **createNote** method looks like this:

```
public int createNote(Note note, Integer userid) {
    return noteMapper.insert(new Note(null, note.getNotetitle(), note.getNotedescription(), userid));
}
```

And the mapper looks like this:

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO CREDENTIALS (notetitle, notedescription, userid) VALUES(#{filename}, #{notetitle}, #{notedescription}, #{userid})")
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "noteid")
int insert(Note note);
```

This is the model:

```
public class Note {
    private Integer noteid;
    private String notetitle;
    private String notedescription;
    private Integer userid;

    public Note(Integer noteid, String notetitle, String notedescription, Integer userid) {
        this.noteid = noteid;
        this.notetitle = notetitle;
        this.notedescription = notedescription;
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public Integer getNoteid() {
        return noteid;
    }

    public void setNoteid(Integer fileId) {
        this.noteid = noteid;
    }

    public String getNotetitle() {
        return notetitle;
    }

    public void setNotetitle(String filename) {
        this.notetitle = notetitle;
    }

    public String getNotedescription() {
        return notedescription;
    }

    public void setNotedescription(String notedescription) {
        this.notedescription = notedescription;
    }

    public Integer getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(Integer userid) { this.userid = userid; }
}
```

And this is the sql schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NOTES (
    noteid INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
    notetitle VARCHAR(20),
    notedescription VARCHAR (1000),
    userid INT,
    foreign key (userid) references USERS(userid)
);
```

When I try to post a note I get an error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No message
> available

When I run it in debug mode it doesn't even get to the controller.
What am I doing wrong here?
This is the [repo](https://github.com/Drax74/nd035-c1-spring-boot-basics-project-starter/tree/master/starter/cloudstorage/src/main/java/com/udacity/jwdnd/course1/cloudstorage).

Comment: Do you have the view `result`? Your controller method seems to return it.

Comment: I do, I have added a link to repo in the question

Comment: i don't see NoteController annotated with @RestController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Leff figured out himself by now, he was simply missing

```
@RestController
public class NoteController {
```

...above his NoteController Class.

`@RestController` tells Spring that the underlying class is a Rest-Endpoint Bean.

@Restcontroller inherits from @Controller, see Spring Boot Doc:

> The first annotation on our Example class is @RestController. This is
> known as a stereotype annotation. It provides hints for people reading
> the code and for Spring that the class plays a specific role. In this
> case, our class is a web @Controller, so Spring considers it when
> handling incoming web requests.
>
> The @RequestMapping annotation provides “routing” information. It
> tells Spring that any HTTP request with the / path should be mapped to
> the home method. The @RestController annotation tells Spring to render
> the resulting string directly back to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Then the API wasn't even exposed.

If you run the project you should get the list of exposed APIs in the log.
Such as

> DEBUG 9736 --- [           main]
> s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 19 mappings in
> 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'

If you use Spring Boot Actuator on intellij: you can check list of API in Endpoints tab, it can be really helpful:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Error 404 usually means you have wrong url. (https://httpstatuses.com/404)

That explains why " it doesn't even get to the controller."

Double check that you are pointing to the right API url

Comment: I just realized that I was missing @controller annotation and that is why it wasn't working

Comment: @Leff exactly, just was gonna tell you that you are missing the @ RestController annotation above your NotesController class.